How to build the jpeg library libjpeg.so as a shared library for android
I am trying to build the jpeg library as a .so file to use it on Android.
This is the jpeg library I want to use.
If you look at that git, there is a .so file, but the architecture I need is arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, x86, x86_64.
So I'm trying to build a .so file for each architecture.
what i did

Create CMakeLists.txt (
A clang error occurred while working on a Mac, so I had to build with CMakeLists.txt.)

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.18.1)

project(libjpeg)

# Include directories
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

# Source files
set(SRC_FILES
    jcapimin.c jcapistd.c jccoefct.c jccolor.c jcdctmgr.c jchuff.c
    jcinit.c jcmainct.c jcmarker.c jcmaster.c jcomapi.c jcparam.c
    jcphuff.c jcprepct.c jcsample.c jctrans.c jdapimin.c jdapistd.c
    jdatadst.c jdatasrc.c jdcoefct.c jdcolor.c jddctmgr.c jdhuff.c
    jdinput.c jdmainct.c jdmarker.c jdmaster.c jdmerge.c jdphuff.c
    jdpostct.c jdsample.c jdtrans.c jerror.c jfdctflt.c jfdctfst.c
    jfdctint.c jidctflt.c jidctfst.c jidctint.c jidctred.c jquant1.c
    jquant2.c jutils.c jmemmgr.c jmemnobs.c
)

# Conditional source files for ARM architecture
if(ANDROID AND (CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI STREQUAL "armeabi-v7a" OR CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI STREQUAL "arm64-v8a"))
    list(APPEND SRC_FILES armv6_idct.S jsimd_arm_neon.S jsimd_neon.c)
endif()

# Conditional source files for x86 architecture
if(ANDROID AND (CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI STREQUAL "x86" OR CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI STREQUAL "x86_64"))
    list(APPEND SRC_FILES jidctintelsse.c)
endif()

# Compiler flags
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -DAVOID_TABLES -O3 -fstrict-aliasing -DANDROID_TILE_BASED_DECODE")

# Conditional compiler flags for ARM architecture
if(ANDROID AND (CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI STREQUAL "armeabi-v7a" OR CMAKE_ANDROID_ARCH_ABI STREQUAL "arm64-v8a"))
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -DNV_ARM_NEON -D__ARM_HAVE_NEON -fno-integrated-as")
    set_source_files_properties(jsimd_arm_neon.S PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-Wa,--noexecstack -no-integrated-as")
endif()


# Define the library
add_library(jpeg SHARED ${SRC_FILES})

# Specify the target properties
set_target_properties(jpeg PROPERTIES
    POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON
)

# Link libraries if necessary (add here if you need to link against other libraries)
#target_link_libraries(jpeg)



run cmake

cmake -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a \
      -DANDROID_PLATFORM=android-21 \
      -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=${ANDROID_NDK_ROOT}/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake \
      -B build/armeabi-v7a

cmake --build build/armeabi-v7a

But I get an error: Below are the logs and error messages from cmake.
[  2%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jcapimin.c.o
[  4%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jcapistd.c.o
[  6%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jccoefct.c.o
[  8%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jccolor.c.o
[ 10%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jcdctmgr.c.o
[ 12%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jchuff.c.o
[ 14%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jcinit.c.o
[ 16%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jcmainct.c.o
[ 18%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jcmarker.c.o
[ 20%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jcmaster.c.o
[ 22%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jcomapi.c.o
[ 25%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jcparam.c.o
[ 27%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jcphuff.c.o
[ 29%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jcprepct.c.o
[ 31%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jcsample.c.o
[ 33%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jctrans.c.o
[ 35%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jdapimin.c.o
[ 37%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jdapistd.c.o
[ 39%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jdatadst.c.o
[ 41%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jdatasrc.c.o
[ 43%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jdcoefct.c.o
[ 45%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jdcolor.c.o
[ 47%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jddctmgr.c.o
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jdhuff.c.o
[ 52%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jdinput.c.o
[ 54%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jdmainct.c.o
[ 56%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jdmarker.c.o
[ 58%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jdmaster.c.o
[ 60%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jdmerge.c.o
[ 62%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jdphuff.c.o
[ 64%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jdpostct.c.o
[ 66%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jdsample.c.o
[ 68%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jdtrans.c.o
[ 70%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jerror.c.o
[ 72%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jfdctflt.c.o
[ 75%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jfdctfst.c.o
[ 77%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jfdctint.c.o
[ 79%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jidctflt.c.o
[ 81%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jidctfst.c.o
[ 83%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jidctint.c.o
[ 85%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jidctred.c.o
[ 87%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jquant1.c.o
[ 89%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jquant2.c.o
[ 91%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jutils.c.o
[ 93%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jmemmgr.c.o
[ 95%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jmemnobs.c.o
[ 97%] Building C object CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/jsimd_neon.c.o
[100%] Linking C shared library libjpeg.so
/Users/sinjeong-won/Desktop/jpeg/jni/jsimd_neon.c:69: error: undefined reference to 'jsimd_ycc_rgba8888_convert_neon'
/Users/sinjeong-won/Desktop/jpeg/jni/jsimd_neon.c:82: error: undefined reference to 'jsimd_ycc_rgb565_convert_neon'
/Users/sinjeong-won/Desktop/jpeg/jni/jsimd_neon.c:91: error: undefined reference to 'jsimd_idct_ifast_neon'
/Users/sinjeong-won/Desktop/jpeg/jni/jsimd_neon.c:100: error: undefined reference to 'jsimd_idct_2x2_neon'
/Users/sinjeong-won/Desktop/jpeg/jni/jsimd_neon.c:108: error: undefined reference to 'jsimd_idct_4x4_neon'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [libjpeg.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/jpeg.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

Please help if you know how to fix the error. thank you

Which source (.c or .S) file defines the functions noted in the error message? (jsimd_ycc_rgba8888_convert_neon, jsimd_ycc_rgb565_convert_neon). Looks like you forgot to add that source file to your library.
